# Yii вывод всех полей

Tags: php, yii

Добрый день!

В процессе разработки, получая данные из базы, бывает удобно написать `select * ...` и в цикле `print_r($fields)`;

Есть ли в `Yii` аналогичная возможность?

Пока нашел только:

```
    $criteria = new CDbCriteria();

    $count=GrabberData::model()->count($criteria);

    $pages=new CPagination($count);

    $pages->pageSize=10;
    $pages->applyLimit($criteria);

    $models = GrabberData::model()->findAll($criteria);

    foreach($models as $m){
         foreach(GrabberData::model()->getMetaData()->tableSchema->columns as $attr)
            { /*...*/ }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public function search()
{

    $criteria=new CDbCriteria;

    foreach($this->getMetaData()->columns as $name=>$column)
    {
        if($column->type==='string')
        {
            $criteria->compare($name,$this->$name,true);
        }
        else
        {
            $criteria->compare($name,$this->$name);
        }
    }

    return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
        'criteria'=>$criteria,
    ));
}
```